# Publish a site created on the new Google Sites through the API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sites

I really love the new Google Sites!

Is there a way to Publish Sites through an API? It's great that we can create and share new Google Sites using the Google Drive API, but I can't see a way to publish a site using the API yet.

Is this feature available, or is there a plan to expose some functionality of the new Google Sites through an API?

Answer (score 1):

The feature for Publishing Website is deprecated through [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/publish-site). However, you can use [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/) which allows client application to access and modify Google Site data using Google Data API feeds. Using the API, applications can create and modify the content of a Google Site, upload and download attachments, review the revision history across a Site, and display recent user activity.

There is a single supported version of the Sites Data API. The documentation includes a guide for each supported way to use the API:

- Java
- Python
- HTTP/XML (Protocol)

Comment: According to the message for the Sites API, at the top of the page you linked, the API for the New Sites is not yet available: "A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. The Sites API cannot access or modify Sites made with this version, but can still access classic Sites."

Comment: Yes, the Sites API is only for the old Google Sites. I was asking specifically about the new Google sites accessed through the Drive API.